# Heteroskedasticity and the other one is the autocorrelation problems in multiple regression analysis

Tags: r, statistics

I am running a multiple linear regression model using `lm` function in R to study the impact of some characteristics on the gene expression level.

My data matrix contains one continuous dependent variable (i.e. gene expression levels) and 50 explanatory variables which are the count of these characteristics on each gene and many of these counts are zeros.

I checked all of the regression assumptions and I found two issues the first one is the Heteroscedasticity and the other one is the autocorrelation problem. The later is not serious. I wonder if using  multiple linear regression is correct or not and if there is any other regression techniques can be used to solve these problems.

I used stepwise method and I got just 11 significant variables among those 50. But when I checked the heteroscedasticity, and I found it still appears as shown below. The sample size is 15,000 genes. (15,000 rows and 50 columns).

[image]

Updated image, with weights added to `lm` call, re comments

[image]

Comment: im voting to migrate this http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions as it needs stats advice

Comment: I checked the autocorrlation using Durbin Watson test and It showed that not serial problem. My main concern here is about heteroscedasticity problem.

Comment: @  Zheyuan Li.I tired to use weighted regression (WLS), but I don't know how to find weights using R.

Comment: Do you mean used it like that:                                                         gene_expr <- lm(m_gene_expression ~., data, weights=1/w)

Comment: I did that and the diagnostic plots got worse than before. Look at the new plots above.